# What to do about key history being re-remembered in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I have used the `history -c` command in terminal, but it only works for the open session.  If I log out and back into command-window-terminal the history is still remembered.  How do I stop this from occurring?

I want to manually delete the history of the typed information in the terminal, permanently, preferably just by command, or with an actual explanation to do, not step skipping tech talk, as I am a low experienced user and the scripting is rarely used and is easy to forget.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You want no history?  What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete typed history manually, on `bash` shell you can delete `.bash_history` file or edit it to remove the lines you want removed.

To check which shell you use type `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: Comes up with bash

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to maintain history between logins, both `bash` and `zsh` have a `HISTFILE` variable.

From `man bash`:

> ```
>  HISTFILE
>        The name of the file in which command history is saved (see HIS-
>        TORY  below).   The default value is ~/.bash_history.  If unset,
>        the command history is  not  saved  when  an  interactive  shell
>        exits.
> ```

From `man zshall` (i.e., all of zsh):

> ```
>   HISTFILE
>        The file to save the history in when an interactive shell exits.
>        If unset, the history is not saved.
> ```

So, if you remove the history file:

```bsh
rm "${HISTFILE}"
```

and add the command to unset it to your shell's rc file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`):

```bsh
unset HISTFILE
```

Then you shouldn't have any history persisted from session to session.

Note that this has the advantage that the history is never written, so if you happen to include sensitive data in your commands, that data doesn't sit around in your history file until it crosses your mind to remove it.

Comment: so there is no terminal command to just delete typed history without remembering it?